# How to create GeoTiff from image and inertial data with GDAL

Tags: qgis, gdal, c++

I am trying to position photos that have seconds of week (utc) in their name with a given inertial data from a file, the file has the following columns:

```
UTCTime   Easting   Northing     H-MSL   Roll   Pitch   Heading
```

Matching the photo UTC time with the record of the inertial file I am trying to build the geotransform, the problem is that it looks like there is a close relation with the degree of the rotation and the pixel size, when I change one of the two, the other changes. For example, with pixel size as 1m photos are correctly rotated and positioned, but below 1m pixel size, the rotation is wrong.

There is barely any information about the world file:

```
The world file is an ASCII text file associated with an image and contains the following lines: 

Line 1: x-dimension of a pixel in map units (A)
Line 2: rotation parameter (B)
Line 3: rotation parameter (C)
Line 4: NEGATIVE of y-dimension of a pixel in map units (D)
Line 5: x-coordinate of center of upper left pixel (E)
Line 6: y-coordinate of center of upper left pixel (F)
```

I am applying the following geotransform (Note, the coordinate is at the center of the photo):

```
(A) pixelSize * Cos(Heading)
(B) Sin(Heading)
(C) Sin(Heading)
(D) -pixelSize * Cos(Heading)
(E) Easting - ((photoWidth / 2 ) * pixelSize)
(F) Northing - ((photoHeight / 2 ) * pixelSize)
```

**How do I compute the geotransform from Easting, Northing, and Heading?**

Note: Heading is in degrees and I convert it to rad. PixelSize is user input.

When the pixel size is less than 1, the image is not properly rotated when I load it on QGIS.

Example:

PixelSize = 1
[image]

PixelSize = 0.1 (The case that mess the rotation pixSize<1)[image]

Im just changing the pixel size in the geotranform and the rotation gets messed up.

Comment: It's more complicated than that, you haven't accounted for pitch (nose up/down), roll (tilt of the planes' wings) and corrected for topography.. locating just based on heading you're not going to be even close to correct.

Comment: I don´t need 100% correct positioning, just estimated one thats why heading is enough. Also to be 100% correct we need to calculate the pixel size with the focal of the lens, which I also didn´t do.